# Restructuring a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, transpose

I have a data look like below:

```
cat1 <- c("A","A","B","B")
gender <- c("male","female","male","female")
mean <- c(1,2,3,4)
sd <-c(5,6,7,8)
data <- data.frame("cat1"=cat1,"gender"=gender, "mean"=mean, "sd"=sd)


> data
  cat1 gender mean sd
1    A   male    1  5
2    A female    2  6
3    B   male    3  7
4    B female    4  8
```

I would like to change the format of the table to this below.

```
> data
  cat1    score    male    female
1    A    mean      1      2
2    A    sd        5      6
3    B    mean      3      4
4    B    sd        7      8
```

Basically, I am alternating between score and cat2 variables.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There are a lot of SO posts already on reshaping or transposing data like this; [here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44400573/5325862)

Comment: @akrun I think if we close the other question as dupe would be better (knowing that I am involved) since here we have multiple working answers (including one that is same as the accepted ans in the dupe-target) versus only one answer there that actually addresses the problem. I dunno if there is a preference over closing newer question over older ones, but if it is not the case, I'd lean toward reopening this one and closing the other. Cheers. (If you agree with the cause, we can later edit this question to make its wording better).

Comment: @M-M I think it is better to remain this as closed.  Duping old with new can create a lot of issues

Answer (score 3):

One option using `gather` and `spread`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  gather(score, value, -cat1, -gender) %>%
  spread(gender, value)

#  cat1 score female male
#1    A  mean      2    1
#2    A    sd      6    5
#3    B  mean      4    3
#4    B    sd      8    7
```

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `melt` and `dcast` from `data.table` package:

```r
library(data.table)

dcast(melt(data, id=c("cat1","gender"), variable.name = "score"), cat1 + score ~ gender)
#>   cat1 score female male
#> 1    A  mean      2    1
#> 2    A    sd      6    5
#> 3    B  mean      4    3
#> 4    B    sd      8    7
```

Generally, any solution that converts the data to *long* format and then reshape it back to *wide* to swap `variable` and `value` columns works here.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with `recast`

```
library(reshape2)
recast(data, id.var = 1:2, cat1 + variable ~ gender)
#   cat1 variable female male
#1    A     mean      2    1
#2    A       sd      6    5
#3    B     mean      4    3
#4    B       sd      8    7
```